# URL removing for anchor tags

Tags: java, html, spring, jsp, jakarta-ee

In my application, the `http://localhost:8080/TestApplication/subCategories/2` will display subcategories of my table with id 2.

`<a href="hello">Click Here</a>`

When I click on the link rendered by the HTML above, my server is redirecting to `http://localhost:8080/SecondOpinion/subCategories/hello`

I want it to redirect to
`http://localhost:8080/SecondOpinion/hello`

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Did you write some code for now ?

Comment: no. Searching for it

Comment: redirect from controller.

Comment: please reframe the question properly, and do check the href link you have inserted , seems like 'sub-categories' is feeded into the href.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is nothing to do with "anchor tags".  An anchor tag is an HTML element of the form `<a name="here">`, and it defines a location within the HTML that another URL can *link to*.

---

What you have is an ordinary HTML link, and what you are seeing is standard HTML behavior for a relative link.

A relative link is resolved related to the "parent" URL for the page containing the link.

If you want a link to go somewhere else, you can:

- Use an absolute URL
- Use path in the relative link; e.g. `Click Here
- Put a `<base href="...">` element into your document's `<head>` section.

In your case, you seem to be<sup>1</sup> combining relative URLs with some unspecified server-side redirection.  In this case, you could either:

- change as above, so that the URL that is sent to the server (before redirection) goes to a better place, or
- change the redirection logic in your server.

I can't tell which would be more appropriate.

---

<sup>1 - I am inferring this because you said *"my server is redirecting to"*.  It is possible that you actually mean that the **browser** is sending that URL to the server, and there is no *redirection* happening at all.</sup>